# How to disable the raised button click animation in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to disable a raisedButton under certain conditions. The animation at the click does not disappear.

Set duration to 0 does not work.

```dart
RaisedButton(
  child: Text((trueCondition ? 'Text...' : '')),
  onPress: () {
    trueCondition = !trueCondition;
    ...
  },
  animationDuration: (trueCondition ? Duration(milliseconds: 700) : Duration(seconds: 0)),
)
```

Comment: Did you figure out the answer for this question ?   I want to disable a button for certain duration. Can you please help me with the code to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check for the condition if the bool value is true if you will pass null so your onPressed will be null and RaisedButton will be disabled, you can also provide the disabled color.

```
onPressed: trueCondition?(){
trueCondition = !trueCondition;
  }: null
```

Answer (score 1):

you can remove tap animation by setting spash & highlight color to transparent

```
MaterialButton(
              splashColor: Colors.transparent,
              highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
              enableFeedback: false,
              onPressed: null,
           ),
```